# How to deal with the noisy cockpit?

Tags: medical, noise

From the pilot perspective I want to know how to deal with the noise in the cockpit on the turboprop aircraft while long-run flights.
The reason is old type aircraft with bad headphones which doesn't protect from noise than they should be.

Comment: Are you not allowed to user your own headset?

Comment: The problem is that headset is very old, reducing noise approximately to 70%.

Answer (score 2):

The most common way to deal with noise in the cockpit is to get yourself a [noise canceling headset](https://www.flyingmag.com/avionics-gear/pilot-supplies/pilot-headsets-review-top-models). There are a bunch of models out there but the most common seem to be the [Bose](http://www.sportys.com/pilotshop/aviation-headsets/bose-aviation-headsets.html) and the [Lightspeed](http://www.sportys.com/pilotshop/aviation-headsets/lightspeed-headsets.html?utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=Aviation%20Headsets&adpos=1t1&creative=161334656346&device=c&matchtype=e&network=g&mrkgcl=596&mrkgadid=3091917028&rkg_id=h-8d045de3e6fef15e0e0cf1841570de7b_t-1514583293&gclid=CjwKCAiA7JfSBRBrEiwA1DWSG7xleZfcAMJoG6RGZslTC_jFjABgAEWLvlTdwjOQsBLujWl2_-7cCBoCyqIQAvD_BwE). I personally have the lightspeed and will attest to at least a 30%-50% perceived noise reduction over my old passive headset.

Comment: I have the problem with connector which doesn't allow to install new headset. AN-26 aircraft

Comment: If the most common way of dealing with noise doesn't work for you, that's something you should definitely state prominently in the question.

Comment: A decent electrical engineer should be able to fabricate a conversion plug to allow a modern ANR headset to work in that aircraft. Well worth the money, imho, in order to preserve your hearing.